# Unicode charecters in android stuido

Tags: android-studio, unicode-string

I am designing a calculator in android and I want to make a button for math pow operation. but instead of X^y, I want the button to show "y" as a propper superscript. also, a special sign for division operation rather than "/". is there a way to do this.
it would best if it was possible to write a line in Values/String.xml file. I can write the special symbol for the registered sign with this code "\u00AE" but codes like division doesn't work this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, ÷, Copy paste this symbol, or alternatively you can use an image.

And as for the power thing. You've control over the whole `UI`, don't take it as a WordPad, why don't you use `TextView` and position it dynamically so that it *looks like* it is in the superscript? Like scaling it down, and translating a bit up in the `y` direction.

Comment: @Rklearner Use `Button` instead, they both have the same positioning tags.

Comment: @Rklearner, And just for information, `OnClickListener`s can also be implemented on `TextView`

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here. Anyway, it's a Linear layout with horizontal orientation if I use a TextView it'll be placed next to the button not in the same place.

Comment: @Rklearner Yes, you can add another LinearLayout within the first one, with different orientation, or just go with [`ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout)